# Some colors are not showing - turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a spirograph code that makes a shape with the given parameters. When I run the code, only the colors white and red work, and blue and green are just presented as white.

```
print('Choose a color: ')
print('1. White')
print('2. Blue')
print('3. Green')
print('4. Red')
color1 = input('-')
```

that part asks for the color that you want

```
if color1 == '1':
    color = 'white'
if color1 == '2':
    color = 'blue'
if color1 == '3':
    color = 'green'
if color1 == '4':
    color = 'red'
elif color1 != '1' or '2' or '3' or '4':
    color = 'white'
```

that part translates the input to a color

```
    draw = True
    t.speed(0)
    num = 0
    t.hideturtle()
    t.pencolor(color) #this part right here
    while draw == True:
        t.circle(90)
        t.rt(rotate)
        num += 1
        if num >= lines:
            draw = False
            print('Press enter to draw again!')
            continue
```

and that is a part of the drawing loop that declares the turtle color as the color that you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your if / else block:

```
if color1 == '1':
    color = 'white'
elif color1 == '2':
    color = 'blue'
elif color1 == '3':
    color = 'green'
elif color1 == '4':
    color = 'red'
else:
    color = 'white'
```

You can also use a list to select the color:

```
color='white'  # default
colorlst = ['white','blue','green','red']
keylst = ['1','2','3','4']
if color1 in keylst:
    color=colorlst[keylst.index(color1)]
```